# Is Unix glob style pattern case sensitive in Python's glob module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, glob

I am not familiarized with [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern style and based on [this tutorial](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/15w/notes/190_glob_patterns.html) it says `glob` is case sensitive.

However, when I use the `glob` module from Python, it seems `glob.glob('./M*')` and `glob.glob('./m*')` return the same results, that is, Python's `glob` is case-**in**sensitive, see below (I print results together to ensure that they are executed in tandem),

[image]

How do I differentiate between upper case and lower case? Do I have to resort to string methods for this sake?

Comment: Thats not possible. Add the exact example run output.

Comment: What's the filesystem type you are globbing on? Some filesystems (eg. NTFS) are case insensitive.

Comment: it's only going to be case sensitive on filesystems that are case sensitive. You used the `unix` tag -- are you running this on a unix system? When I ran your command I didn't get the results you claim you get.

Comment: @BryanOakley I ran on Windows 10 system that is boot camped from Mac system. Based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity), MacOS is case-insensitive and case-preserving. I guess this is why I cannot have separate files, say, readme.txt and Readme.txt in the same directory, i.e., it's case-insensitive in Python's glob module. What's your take?

Comment: @Nicholas: you are correct. On a Mac with a default configuration, `Readme.txt` and `readme.txt` both refer to the same file.

Answer (score 5):

From the [glob source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/glob.py#L39), you can see that it uses `os.path.lexists` which is backended with `lstat` (falls back to `os.path.exists` if `lstat` is not available). `glob` itself does nothing to alter the case sensitivity. This is determined by the file system on which the file exists.

```
[aarcher@Arch]: /tmp/test>$ rm -rf * && touch moo
[aarcher@Arch]: /tmp/test>$ python -q
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("m*")
['moo']
>>> glob.glob("M*")
[]
>>>
```

Comment: But could you explain further how do I know what file system I am using and if it's case sensitive? Is this property changeable?

Comment: Write two files with the same name. Example: `echo 1 > test && echo 2 > TEST && cat test`